# saving the correct data in the html form

Tags: php, mysql

I have a registration panel in my web application.

I have created a bool variable that is true, which must do some if-else statements that can change it to false. If this variable remains true, it allows you to register a new user.

It often happens that the user correctly fills 3 out of 4 inputs, but when he presses submit, he cleans all forms for one wrongly filled input.

I would like to be able to save values in the form, if the bool variable test was correct. How to do it?

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: Without code for context it's anyone's guess what you're doing and how to fix it.  Do you have a minimal example you can include with an edit so we can see what you're doing?